# Could a convicted felon run for US Presidency from prison?

Tags: united-states, president

Assuming that the FBI raid leads to charges being filed against Donald Trump and a court sentences him to a prison sentence, could he still run for President from within a jail cell? And if he does win, would the government be forced to release him for the duration of his term?

Comment: I don't think the answers in the linked thread have answered the question entirely - can a felon run for president (YES), effectively from jail (no precedent, so who knows).